# Boostrap multiple inputs inside a input-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to do something pretty simple but for several days I'm working on but no luck.
I need to do something like this:

[image]

So I need one input, space, 2 inputs next to each other, space, a button.

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="field1"/>
            </div>


            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="field2"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="field3"/>
            </div>


        </div>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">My button</button>
    </form>

    </div>
```

and it gives this:

[image]

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for any idea.

C.C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can have two inputs in one group. Here's a not so clean way to do it, but it works: http://www.bootply.com/B4GIyi2E2l

```
<div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="field1">
            </div>


             <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="field1">
            </div>

          <div class="input-group" style="margin-left:-10px">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="field1">
            </div>
```

Or you can try it this way with inline styling:

http://www.bootply.com/RkhHZbahVE

Comment: Yes, not so clean, but the inline styling is pretty good. If no other solution possible, I will use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#custom-forms) is the official guide about that issue:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Options</label>
  </div>
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect02">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect02">Options</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect03">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```